# Laravel работа в фоне

Tags: php, laravel

Жизненный цикл контроллера, грубо говоря предполагает, что он обработает запрос пользователя, и вернёт вью. Но для моей задачи это не годится, к примеру есть приложение для ВК на ларавел, и нужно раз в неделю присылать пользователю оповещение о том, чтобы он "зашёл в приложение". Получается тут нет запроса пользователя, а лишь сервер смотрит время, и по истечению его делает какое-то действие. С помощью чего это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ознакомьтесь с разделом [команд](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan)
Вешаете на крон задачу по [расписанию](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling)
Не уверен что вам для этого нужна вся мощь Laravel, можно воспользоваться и другими инструментами в которых есть схожий функционал и только. Например возможно лучше поставить Lumen только с теми пакетами которые вам нужны